# Int to String formula expression (Pentaho Report Designer)

Tags: expression, formula, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm attempting to write a formula expression in Pentaho Report Designer 3.9.  The expression will take the SEMIANNUAL1_VALUE attribute which is an int or number-field and display "N/A" when the value is -1.   Below is the expression I currently have that is not working.

```
=IF([SEMIANNUAL1_VALUE] = -1 ; TEXT("N/A"); [SEMIANNUAL1_VALUE] )
```

I have this expression in the "value field" in Pentaho Report Designer which should handle this exception.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the solution wrong. You can't have code that in one hand returns a string, on the other returns a number. Thats never sensible!  Think in the case where you wanted to use this field in further expressions later on etc - not just the case of displaying the field on the report.

The solution is simply to return NA() rather than TEXT("N/A")  Which will return null. Then set the ifnull flag on the numeric field to be "N/A".  That works.  Because ifnull is just the display property of the field this works fine.